# Adding target url to google map sidebar buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I've installed the following Sidebar with makeMarker for google maps and it's working fine. However, I would like to have the sidebar list/places(buttons) to also have a target url so that they can show/hide other hidden info on the page.

```
var mapOpts = {
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
scaleControl: true,
scrollwheel: false
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOpts);
//  We set zoom and center later by fitBounds()

/**
* makeMarker() ver 0.2
* creates Marker and InfoWindow on a Map() named 'map'
* creates sidebar row in a DIV 'sidebar'
* saves marker to markerArray and markerBounds
* @param options object for Marker, InfoWindow and SidebarItem
* @author Esa 2009
*/
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var markerArray = [];

function makeMarker(options){
var pushPin = new google.maps.Marker({map:map});
pushPin.setOptions(options);
google.maps.event.addListener(pushPin, "click", function(){
infoWindow.setOptions(options);
infoWindow.open(map, pushPin);
if(this.sidebarButton)this.sidebarButton.button.focus();
});
var idleIcon = pushPin.getIcon();
if(options.sidebarItem){
pushPin.sidebarButton = new SidebarItem(pushPin, options);
pushPin.sidebarButton.addIn("sidebar2");
}
markerBounds.extend(options.position);
markerArray.push(pushPin);
return pushPin;
}

google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(){
infoWindow.close();
});
/**
* Creates an sidebar item 
* @constructor
* @author Esa 2009
* @param marker
* @param options object Supported properties: sidebarItem, sidebarItemClassName,   
  sidebarItemWidth,
*/
function SidebarItem(marker, opts){
var tag = opts.sidebarItemType || "button";
var row = document.createElement(tag);
row.innerHTML = opts.sidebarItem;
row.className = opts.sidebarItemClassName || "sidebar_item";  
row.style.display = "block";
row.style.width = opts.sidebarItemWidth || "180px";
row.onclick = function(){
google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
}
row.onmouseover = function(){
google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'mouseover');
}
row.onmouseout = function(){
google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'mouseout');
}
this.button = row;
}
// adds a sidebar item to a <div>
SidebarItem.prototype.addIn = function(block){
if(block && block.nodeType == 1)this.div = block;
else
this.div = document.getElementById(block)
|| document.getElementById("sidebar2")
|| document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
this.div.appendChild(this.button);
}
// deletes a sidebar item
SidebarItem.prototype.remove = function(){
if(!this.div) return false;
this.div.removeChild(this.button);
return true;
}
/**
* markers and info window contents
*/
makeMarker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(39.924186, -75.297571),
title: "Royal Legends VBC",
sidebarItem: "Royal Legends VBC",
content: "Royal Legends VBC"
});   
makeMarker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.152785, -76.750233),
title: "Yorktowne VBC",
sidebarItem: "Yorktowne VBC",
content: "Yorktowne VBC"
});  
makeMarker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(39.962254, -75.605264),
title: "Lokahi",
sidebarItem: "Lokahi",
content: "Lokahi"
}); 
makeMarker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.152785, -76.750233),
title: "Yorktowne VBC",
sidebarItem: "Yorktowne VBC",
content: "Yorktowne VBC"
});   
/**
*   fit viewport to markers
*/
map.fitBounds(markerBounds);
```

And here is the jquery to show and hide.

```
jQuery(function(){
 jQuery('#showall').click(function(){
       jQuery('.targetDiv').show();
});
jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){
      jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
      jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
});
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: can pass more options like `target` into `makeMarker` objects to use for relationship to other content and add more logic to the event handlers already being assigned to each button. Can use jQuery within those event handlers also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of passing more data into sidebarItem through makeMarker

```
makeMarker({
    /* new option*/
    target:'somVal',

    position: new google.maps.LatLng(39.924186, -75.297571),
    title: "Royal Legends VBC",
    sidebarItem: "Royal Legends VBC",
    content: "Royal Legends VBC"
});
```

Then in click handler within setItem:

```
row.onclick = function(){
     google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
     jQuery ('.content_selected').hide().removeClass('content_selected');
     jQuery('#div'+opts.target).show().addClass('content_selected');;

}
```

Adjust other button event handlers accordingly

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl. That worked as far as showing the hidden element when clicked but didn't hide eleemnt when clicking on another sidebar button. I'm guessing that would be another makeMarker call out... Thanks again. KM

Comment: can hide th whole class of elements that are the other content if that helps...usually easiest that way. Or, add a `selected` class to the one you show within code I gave you...then use that class to hide, then remove the `selected` class before applying to new one

Comment: added toggling class concept to my answer

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl. That works great now except it doesn't hide the first element when selecting the second button but does so after selecting the first button twice. Have a look for reference. Thanks for your help. I haven't used google maps very much and it's been quite the lesson. http://www.fishmooredesign.com/KRVA/adults_clubs_test2.php. Also I'm hiding the divs with the following: <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
    $('#div2, #div3, #div4').hide();
    });
</script>

Comment: just need to add `content_selected` class in html to default one...usually easiest to use a common class for the hide stuff rather than `#id1,#id2,#id3`...then if you add a new one don't need to change selector

Comment: ok..simplify..just add `content_selected` to the one that displays by default on page load in the html

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl. Working great now. Cheers!